# How do I answer to an answer?

Tags: support

I see people starting discussions based on an answer, but I can only seem to reply to the original question?

I must be missing something for sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 50 rep to leave comments on posts that aren't your own.

https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Darn, that'll teach me to finish reading the FAQ. But...programmers and 'reading the manual' seem kinda incompatible ;o)

Comment: PS you should totally mark this answer as *accepted*.

Comment: Whoops! Done!...